# UIDatePicker: Add constraint to time

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, datetime-format

Is there a way to limit/constraint time on the UIDatePicker.

i.e. if I want the picker to show time only from 3:00PM - 8:00PM, nothing before of after that time, is that possible?

Code example would be nice.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{


    // **EDIT 2**
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setMinute:10];
    [comps setHour:5];
    NSDate *minimumTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];


    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];

    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [pickerView setMinimumDate:minimumTime];

    [pickerView setMinuteInterval:15];
    [pickerView setTag: kDatePickerTag1];
    //Add picker to action sheet
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
    NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
}
```

startTimeLabel is an NSString variable (i.e. 6:30 PM) that should be used as minimum time on the UIPicker.

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
[datePicker setMaximumDate:yourmaxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:yourminDate];
```

To create a NSDate:

```
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate:todaysDate];
[comps setMinute:10];
[comps setHour:5];
[comps setSecond:0];
NSDate *yourminDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the code above and it's not working.  I have updated the post.

Comment: I still see the full-24 hours in the picker.

Comment: @user1107173 Use date components.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nope.  I updated it with Edit 2.  Please see above.  The picker still shows the full 24 hours.  Sorry, if I'm missing something obvious.  I'm two hours away from breaking my 17 hours fast.

Comment: @user1107173 In your date picker can you set the month and day?

Comment: @user1107173 I re-edited my answer. It should work. I tested it myself.

Comment: It should be showing time past 5:10AM right?  It's still showing full-24 hours.  I'll upload an image.

Comment: @user1107173 Yes, but the UIDatePicker won't allow you to go to a time under 5:10. See how the 4 is greyed out?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I was under the impression it's not suppose to show at all.  You are right.  Thanks!  Why is the interval 1:15, when I have it set at     [pickerView setMinuteInterval:15];

Comment: @user1107173 The datePicker is at a interval of 15 minutes.

Comment: hahaha..I'm sorry.  It's too early!  Thank you for your help!